# Adding a collection of objects to Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have a domain collection type called SavedAnswers and would like to add that collection to my Entity Framework type Entries. I've been trying to figure out what I need to do but I'm getting confused on all the information out there.

Answers has a Identity Primary Key and two Foreign Keys, which brings more issues/questions.

```
    public void AddEntries(List<SavedAnswers> answers)
    {
        foreach (var item in answers)
        {
            db.Entries.AddObject(Entries.CreateEntries(1, item.QuestionId, item.AnswerId));
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I just have no idea if I'm doing it the correct way.

Comment: Yes, except one thing that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good except that you should not use the generated factory method on your *Entry* object. Instead, just create it via the constructor and populate it with object initializer:

```
public void AddEntries(List answers) {
    foreach (var item in answers) {
        db.Entries.AddObject(new Entry()
        {
            QuestionId = item.QuestionId, 
            AnswerId   = item.AnswerId
        });
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When you use [*ObjectSet.AddObject*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277.aspx) method to add newly created objects that do not exist in the store, the entity will get an automatically generated temporary *EntityKey* and its *EntityState* will be set to *Added*.

Comment: It works! Thanks for adding in the explanation about the EntityKey and State.